# Show that $\mathfrak{m}_p$ is an ideal in $\mathcal{O}_V.$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, field-theory, ideals, algebraic-curves, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I'm working through *Algebraic Geometry: A Problem Solving Approach* by Garrity et al, and I have found myself stuck on Exercise 4.13.1, which is the section *Points and Local Rings*.

> Let $V = V(x^2 + y^2 - 1) \subset \mathbb{A}^2(k).$ Let $p = (1, 0)
>  \in V.$ Define $$\mathfrak{m}_p = \{f \in \mathcal{O}_V : f(p) =
>  0\}.$$
>
> Show that $\mathfrak{m}_p$ is a maximal ideal in
> $\mathcal{O}_V.$

We're told that $\mathcal{O}_V$ is a subring of the function field $\mathcal{K}_V = \{\frac{f}{g} : f, g \in \mathcal{O}(V), g \neq 0\},$ where $\mathcal{O}(V) = k[x, y]/I(V).$

It was easy enough to show that $\mathfrak{m}_p$ is an ideal, but I'm getting caught up on how to show that it is maximal.

I know that maximal ideals in $k[x, y]$ are all of the form $I = \langle x - a_1, y - a_2 \rangle,$ so my idea was to show that $\mathfrak{m}_p = \langle x - 1, y \rangle,$ and then I know that maximal ideals in $k[x, y]/I(V)$ correspond to maximal ideal in $k[x, y]$ containing $I(V).$ This feels close to something correct, but I think I just don't understand the different spaces well enough to put it all together. Also, $\mathfrak{m}_p$ is an ideal in $\mathcal{O}_V,$ while $\langle x - 1, y\rangle$ is an ideal in $k[x, y],$ so setting them equal to each other doesn't make any sense.

Comment: What does the condition $f(p) = 0$ mean if $f$ is not defined at $p$? If we just exclude all such $f$ from $\mathfrak{m}_p$ we have an issue: then $\mathfrak{m}_p$ is not neccesarily an ideal of $\mathcal{O}_V$! For example, if $\mathcal{O}_V = \mathcal{K}_V$, then $y \in \mathfrak{m}_p$ but $y/(1-x) \notin \mathfrak{m}_p$. This issue might be fixed if we had more information about $\mathcal{O}_V$ beyond "it's a subring of $\mathcal{K}_V$"; for example, if $\mathcal{O}_V = \mathcal{O}(V)$ there is no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map $\mathcal{O}_V \to k$, $f \mapsto f(p)$. Show this is a ring homomorphism with kernel $\mathfrak{m}$.

Comment: One must also show that this is surjective, which requires something stronger than $\mathcal{O}_V$ being a subring of $\mathcal{K}_V$! For example, the prime subring of $\mathcal{K}_V$ need not surject onto $k$ (consider the case $k = \mathbb{F}_4$). Am I missing something? Perhaps we are meant to assume that $\mathcal{O}_V$ is a sub-$k$-algebra of $\mathcal{K}_V$?

Comment: @diracdeltafunk We have the constant functions in $\mathcal{O}_V$.

Comment: Sorry, what I'm saying is that, in OP's post, the only information we're given about $\mathcal{O}_V$ is that it is a subring of $\mathcal{K}_V$ (in particular, strangely, $\mathcal{O}_V$ might not be the coordinate ring $\mathcal{O}(V)$ of the variety!) Thus, there may be constant functions in $\mathcal{K}_V$ which are not in $\mathcal{O}_V$. For example, let $k = \mathbb{Q}$ and let $\mathcal{O}_V = \mathbb{Z}$; then $\mathfrak{m}_p = 0$ is not maximal in $\mathcal{O}_V$. Being a subring of $\mathcal{K}_V$ is also too weak a condition for another reason; see my comment on the question above.

Comment: This is of course not an issue with your answer, which is absolutely the intended solution, just a note that OP's problem statement can't be correct.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk my mistake, read the OP too fast

Comment: I don't know if it's an issue with the book or if I missed something, but they don't seem to give any more info on $\mathcal{O}_V.$ The only reason that I even knew it was a subring was from the introduction to the section: "The goal of this section is to show how to link points on an algebraic variety $V$ with local rings $\mathcal{O}_V,$ which are subrings of the function field $\mathcal{K}_V.$" And then this problem appears a few paragraphs later without another mention of $\mathcal{O}_V.$

Comment: Ah, this resolves the quandary. Here $\mathcal{O}_V$ is meant to be the subring of $\mathcal{K}_V$ consisting of those rational functions which are defined at $p$, a.k.a. $\mathcal{O}_V = \{f/g : f,g \in \mathcal{O}(V), g(p) \neq 0\}$. This is an abuse of notation because $\mathcal{O}_V$ depends on the point $p$, and a particularly egregious one because the dependence of $\mathfrak{m}_p$ on $p$ *is* made explicit, and there's nothing special about the point $(1,0)$. Anyway, this ring is usually called $\mathcal{O}_{V,p}$ and using this specific ring resolves all the problems I've mentioned.

Comment: That makes sense. That definition actually shows up shortly after this problem: $\mathcal{O}_p(V) = \{\frac{f}{g} \in \mathcal{K}_V : g(p) \neq 0\}.$

Comment: As a side note, as I'm sure you see already, the proof does generalize and work whenever $\mathcal{O}_V$ is a sub-$k$-algebra of $\mathcal{O}_p(V)$.